# testng-failed.xml is not getting generated even if the run contains failures

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

testng-failed.xml is not getting generated  even if the run contains failures.

I am using 
Eclipse
Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
Build id: 20190614-1200

Testng 7.0.0

This used to generate some time before and we were using it for rerunning the failed tests. But i am not sure why this is not generating now even if the errors are present.

Is there any specific reason that it wouldn't generate?

Comment: Have you started using Maven with surefire plugin to execute your tests, in that case you might not be seeing the testng-failed.xml under test-output folder as Maven testng code might be disabling all the internal testng reports. check out - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/WvmSI_yKDc0

Comment: @NitishKshirsagar this is a simple plain execution from testngplugin in eclipse

Comment: Update- Now it started to generate again. Not sure what caused it to stop or start. In between i did mvn clean install. One of my colleague ran into this issue but the clean install didn't help him. so the rootcause still remains unknown.

Comment: Update:  I see that this happens only when there is a listener capturing all the fails and skips. 

question: . how do we generate testng-failed.xml when using the listener ITestListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this happens only when there is a listener which  captures all the fails and skips. 
On removing the listener failed.xml created successfully.